# Android AsyncTask loading screen never goes away

Tags: android, android-asynctask

My problem is I'm loading some data from web service and I want to inform the user I'm loading data. Because of that I'm using AsyncTask but my Datagetter method doesn't work and I can't figure out why. Here is my class:

```
public class HaberlerDynamic extends Activity {

    ArrayList<ArrayList> result = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();
    ListView list;
    DynamicListView haber ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.kurumsal_menu);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        new GetTask(this ,"gereksiz").execute();
    }


    class GetTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Void> {
        Context context;
        ProgressDialog mDialog ;

        GetTask(Context context, String userid) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            mDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            mDialog.setMessage("Yükeniyor...");
            mDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Object... params) {
            // here you can get the details from db or web and fetch it..

            Log.i("HaberlerDynamicAs","Request yapmadan once");
            try {    
                //this part does not work
                result = MethodInfoGetter.methodRequest("HaberGetir", "", "");

                //this part does not work
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            haber = new DynamicListView( HaberlerDynamic.this , result , "Haberler" );

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            mDialog.dismiss();
            list.setAdapter( haber );

        }
    }
}
```

And if I don't use AsyncTask and call that part in onCreate it works perfectly.

**EDIT:**

Method InfoGetter.methodRequest("HaberGetir", "", ""); this method has its own async method inside. Will it effect that ?

**EDIT2:**

Moving the method list.setAdapter( haber ); from `doInBackground` to `onPostExecute` still doesn't change anything.

Comment: `list.setAdapter( haber );` updating ui from `doInbackground` is wrong

Comment: where should I put that code ?

Comment: I put this code " list.setAdapter( haber );" into onPostExecute but it didn't work either.

Comment: @EsatTaha "does not work" specify what does not work and what is the problem. You have a exception? a crash?

Comment: No I dont have any exception or any crash. But progress dialog never goes away.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48083/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-esat-taha)

Answer (score 0):

```
 1. list.setAdapter(haber); -->Remove this line from doInbackground
```

You can't set UI in doInBackground thread

2.setAdapter onPostExecute

```
 list.setAdapter(haber);
```